# how to import celery tasks in django views

Tags: python, django, celery, celery-task

I am learning celery with django. I am trying to create a simple addition project with django and celery. I created a simple webapp with django. in the index.html template, I have a form with 2 input fields. The first input field takes the `x value` (the first number for addition). The second input field takes `y value` (the second number for addition). When the form is submitted, I want the celery task to run. The django project name is ***core*** and the app name is ***mainapp***

The celery task is as follows

**mainapp/tasks.py**

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def add_num(x, y):
    return x+y
```

**core/celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')

app = Celery('core')
app.conf.timezone = 'UTC'
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

**mainapp/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import tasks

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        x = request.POST['x']
        y = request.POST['y']

        print(x, y)

        add_num.delay(x, y)

        return render(request, 'index.html')

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

I have rabbitmq running in the background with the following command

```
brew services start rabbitmq
```

celery is running in a separate terminal window with the following command

```
celery -A core worker -B -l INFO
```

When I submit the form I get the following error.

```
NameError: name 'add_num' is not defined
```

I guess I am not importing the tasks into views.py properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incorrect import

change below line

```
from . import tasks
```

to

```
from .tasks import add_num
```